# PHP ZipArchive, how to increase compression rate?

Tags: php, compression, archive, php-ziparchive

I'm using PHP ZipArchive for compressing folder in PHP.

The files and the subfolders are well added to the archive, but I would like to know how to increase the compression level of the archive.

The following code is based on the exemple of this commit : https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/3a55ea02

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "output/a.zip";

if (!$zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE)) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt", "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
$zip->addFile('output/done/monday/pdftest.pdf', 'test.pdf');

$zip->setCompressionName("test.pdf", ZipArchive::CM_DEFLATE, 6);
$zip->setCompressionIndex(2, ZipArchive::CM_DEFLATE, 6);

$zip->close();
```

The compression is not enougth.

- Archive weight : 7 690 288 bytes
- PDF File"output/done/monday/pdftest.pdf" weight : 7 809 870 bytes

For this exemple, I would like that the archive weight be less than 5 000 000 bytes.

Is any anyone hase a solution for define a real compression level ?

Thanks by advance for your help and have a good week.

Mickaël

Comment: I may be ask a silly question, but are you sure the files inside your archive can be compressed ? Already compressed files such as JPEG can't be compressed more, whatever algorithm choosed (zip, rar, etc.). If you have many non-text files, compression ratios can be poor

Comment: I assume you realise that PDFs already have a reasonable level of compression and 
zlib files aren't compressible.

Comment: Hey, thankz for your answer ! Effectively... my test cases were bad... I've tested with a big sql file and a big BMP image file... the difference is obvious ! But , I've tried to set differents compression level, and the result is still the same (the generated archive file has always the same weight...), I've also realized that if I disable the code lines that set the compression... the generated archive file has is the same weight. SO I'm always thinking that there is something that I do wrong.